# Sort Entire Worksheet down to the last row

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, error-handling

i have a macro that sorts all my data based on a custom sort but i want to use it on different worksheets that has different last row "number" if so to speak and i have this code here but i keep getting an error:

and just so that u know i am sorting column O

```
Sub SortDays()

' SortDays Macro



lRow = Worksheets("Banner Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B1").Select
Range("A1:A" & lRow).Select
Range("O2").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Banner Summary").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Banner Summary").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "O2:O" & lRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
    "M,T,W,R,F", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Banner Summary").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

The error is: "The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that...."
it is quite long so any help would be really appreciated, and thnx in advance ^_^

Comment: Your setrange needs to include column O as well.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the worksheet you want to sort:

```
Sub SortDays(byRef ws)

' SortDays Macro
lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'Range("B1").Select
'Range("A1:A" & lRow).Select
'Range("O2").Activate
ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "O2:O" & lRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
    "M,T,W,R,F", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ws.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:O" & lRow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Then this will run on any worksheet you pass it (assuming you have defined `ws` as whichever worksheet you want to use anyway:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet : Set ws = Workbooks("excelfilename").Worksheets("WhateverSheet")
```

prior to calling the `Sub` with `SortDays ws`